# Construction Industry Vendor management

Tags: database

Is anybody aware of a solution for managing vendors without having to create a unique database from scratch?

I'm looking for the following features:

Need:

- Ability to assign notes to vendor
- Ability to assign ratings to performance (think Yelp)
- Ability to    maintain generic list of projects
- Ability to assign vendors to projects
- Ability to assign 2-layers of vendors (i.e. assign level 1 vendor:
  manufacturer and a level 2 vendor: contractor)
- Ability to assign vendors as "types" such as "plumber" or "HVAC
  contractor"

Nice-to-haves:

- Ability to assign vendors to regions
- Ability to preliminarily assign multiple vendors to projects prior to
  final selection

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the open source CRM systems like [SuiteCRM](https://suitecrm.com/) for this:

- You can set up a Vendor as an "Account".
- You can add a  new "Vendor Type" field via its "Studio" to denote Manufacturer/Contractor or sub-types like Plumber etc.
- It has Notes so can be assigned to Vendor.
- For ratings, you can also create an additional field via its "Studio".
- It has a "Projects" facility which can be created and assigned to Vendors.
- Ability to assign 2-layers of vendors: depends on what you mean here. But I believe can be done once appropriate fields created.
- It is PHP/MySql, Open source, so can be self-hosted.
- It probably has much more than you need (Calls, Meetings, etc). So you may have to hide or disable some of the modules.